# Jmeter- scripts not recording using exter

Tags: jmeter

I am working on trying to record using jmeter but nothing records. My webserver is an application that you launchwhich then runs in the background. I then type in my url and it  like http//localhost:80/clocking and I get into our web application. so it is not something that is on the web but and webserver exe that is launched which does the buisness. Is it possible to records scripts with jmeter in this case

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

Just ensure when using browser that in your proxy configuration you don't have some No Proxy for **localhost** and ensure of course that your proxy points to jmeter (localhost , port 8888 as of jmeter 2.12)

Answer (score 0):

Jmeter Listens between proxy and your machine.

If your application is locally deployed on your machine then you dont another proxy.

Set system network settings from default browser/IE like,

```
proxy : localhost
port : 80
```

If you have application on deployed on external web server i.e. outside your local machine or corporate proxy then you need to invoke Jmeter with corporate proxy like,

```
Jmeter.bat -H <hostname - corporate proxy> -P <port> -u <username> -a <pwd>
```

This way JMeter listens whatever comes to your proxy.